# Double Pivot. No Aggregate then Aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server

OK So I posed the other day about a pivot and the moderator just pointed me at another question and it wasn't the answer, but I found my own on another site.  This has to do with the same SQL but I need to do a double pivot.

This is my code

```
CREATE TABLE #tempBene
(accountID varchar(8), 
beneName1 varchar(30),
beneamount1 decimal(12,0)
)


INSERT INTO #tempBene
(accountID, beneName, beneamount)
VALUES
('1', 'One', 1),
('1', 'OneTwo',  1),
('1', 'OneThree',  1),
('1', 'OneFour',  1),
('1', 'OneFive',  1),
('1', 'OneSix',  1),

('2', 'TwoOne', 2),
('2', 'TwoTwo',  2),
('2', 'TwoThree',  2),

('3', 'ThreeOne', 3),
('3', 'ThreeTwo',  3),
('3', 'ThreeThree',  3),

('4', 'FourOne', 4),
('4', 'FourTwo',  4),

('5', 'FiveOne', 5)

SELECT ACCOUNTID, [1] as BENE1,  [2] as Bene2, [3] as Bene3, [4] as Bene4, [5] as Bene5 
    INTO #TempBene
    FROM 
    (SELECT ACCOUNTID,  BeneficiaryName
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountID ORDER BY ACCOUNTID)
    AS ROWNUM
    FROM #TempAccount
    WHERE DELETEFLAG = 'N') a
    PIVOT (MAX(BENEFICIARYName) FOR RowNUM IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])) AS  pvt
```

The first pivot above gets around the aggregate and gives me what part of what I need.

I get

```
ACCOUNTID Bene1  BENE2       BENE3      BENE4      BENE5
1         one     onetwo
2         twoone  twotwo     twothree   twofour    twofive
```

What I need, and I can not figure out is how to include an amount with that as I am not doing an aggregate.

I need

```
AccountID     Bene1     BeneAmt1     Bene2     BeneAmount2   ...
1             one        1           onetwo    1
2             onetwo     2           twotwo    2
```

Sorry if this is simple to some but I am nto able to add in my amounts that go with each record and maintain my pivot.

Thanks

Comment: It is a little difficult to follow you because you gave us test data but reference another temp table and make it seem like we don't have  example data reflecting your actual schema.  Like you are giving us the second half of the issue transforming from first pivot to second.  But almost anytime you need to pivot more than once you shouldn't use PIVOT instead you should use conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it by not using PIVOT but using conditional aggregation.

```
select  a.accountID,
        MAX(CASE WHEN rowNum = 1 THEN beneName END) AS Bene1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN rowNum = 1 THEN beneAmount END) AS BeneAmt1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN rowNum = 2 THEN beneName END) AS Bene2,
        SUM(CASE WHEN rowNum = 2 THEN beneAmount END) AS BeneAmt2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN rowNum = 3 THEN beneName END) AS Bene3,
        SUM(CASE WHEN rowNum = 3 THEN beneAmount END) AS BeneAmt3,
        MAX(CASE WHEN rowNum = 4 THEN beneName END) AS Bene4,
        SUM(CASE WHEN rowNum = 4 THEN beneAmount END) AS BeneAmt4,
        MAX(CASE WHEN rowNum = 5 THEN beneName END) AS Bene5,
        SUM(CASE WHEN rowNum = 5 THEN beneAmount END) AS BeneAmt5,
        MAX(CASE WHEN rowNum = 6 THEN beneName END) AS Bene6,
        SUM(CASE WHEN rowNum = 6 THEN beneAmount END) AS BeneAmt6
FROM    (
            SELECT  *,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY accountID ORDER BY accountID) AS rowNum
            FROM    #tempBene 
        ) a
GROUP BY a.accountID
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was locked into the Pivot and was not thinking outside that box.  This worked as intended